# Json DateTime 19 digits long?

Tags: json, datetime, unix, time, converters

I am working on a webrequest, and the last part of it is (for exemple) : 
    `...&cb=jQuery1702547129448580113_1468872275121`

I was sure this relies to the DateTime the Get request is send to the server, and `1468872275121` indeed is `18/07/2016 20:04:35` UTC (converted from Json/Unix  date format).

Ok good.

But any idea **what could be the first part** ?? Is it also a DateTime value ? *(the request is sent when adding some item to your cart on a commercial site)*
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default for dates in JSON is a string in RFC 3339 or IS 8601 format, like "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z". You will also find dates stored as a number storing either seconds or milliseconds since midnight, Jan 1st. 1970 in UTC.

A year has about 30 million seconds. Compare that with the number that you see.

Comment: Right, the second part is the date in the format you provided :) But I need to find out **what the first part** represent, or how it might be encoded to be able to replicate the GET WebRequest